# Show child nodes and hide parent node on parent node click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

What I am trying to create is very similar to a jQuery tree but nodes will not display by collapsing and expanding under their parent, but the div will show the children only instead of showing parent and children together. Then I could have a button to go back to display their parent only again.

Example:

I have a parent node in a div,

once I click on a "parent" node, this div then kind of refresh and display its child nodes only(hide/remove parent node from top) with a button to go back to previous parent node display.

I have serialized the hierarchy from a json file and cached at front end, and tried to use codes below:

```
document.getElementById('parent').parentNode.style.display='none';
```

or

```
.parent
{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

but could not get to what I want.

Any hint?  Especially I am not sure if there is any "cooked" open source lib could achieve it(coz it's different than a jQuery tree). I have no idea about the key word to search(like the structure name).

Any hint or any key word to search will be appreciated!

Comment: not possible. once you hide a parent node, all child nodes are hidden as well. think of it this way: if the invisible man's invisibility was only skin-deep (parent node), then all the child nodes (guts/blood/bones) would be visible.

Comment: So what if we forget about the tree structure, as I have cached all the nodes at front end, how about to have client side refresh once click on parent node? Kind of re-render the div by node click. @MarcB

Comment: you can rejigger your structure, so instead of `<parent><child /></parent>`, you end up with a parallel `<parent1 /><child1 /><parent2 /><child2 />`-type thing. then if you hide any of the "parents", the children aren't affected. it's more nodes to have to iterate over and show/hide, but you at least don't have to deal with the hidden parent/hidden child problem.

Answer (score 0):

Marc B is right, you can't really hide the parent and show the children. The next best thing is to throw in a toggle element under the true parent element. A simple example might be:

```
$('.parent-toggle').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('.parent').find('.child').show()
  $(this).closest('.parent').find('.parent-toggle').hide()
});
```

[Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/u5aqsrhx/). Note that `visibility: hidden` doesn't remove the space the parent element in question takes up. I've used `display: none` to completely hide the element, but change as you wish.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. That is a great solution but toggle will work if I only have two levels of nodes. Actually I need to go deeper and deeper. So what if we forget about the tree structure, as I have cached all the nodes at front end, how about to have client side refresh once click on parent node? Kind of re-render the div by node click.